# MySQL Order query response by number of matches on another row

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables:

colleges (id) and users_colleges (user_id, college_id)

I want to select all colleges the current user doesn't have (user_id != @current_user) ordering by the number of matches in user_colleges table, even if it's 0.

What I'm trying with no success:

```
SELECT b.id, COUNT(b.id) AS count
FROM (`users_colleges` AS a)
RIGHT JOIN `colleges` AS b ON `b`.`id` = `a`.`college_id`
GROUP BY `b`.`id`
ORDER BY COUNT(b.id) DESC
```

This is returning all colleges ordered the correct way. The problem is that colleges with no matches the count is returning 1 (should be 0) and it's also returning colleges the user already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count the field that is in the table which is outer joined. This means that it doesn't count the NULL values when the join fails.

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(uc.college_id) AS count
FROM colleges AS c
LEFT JOIN users_colleges AS uc
ON c.id = uc.college_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY COUNT(uc.college_id) DESC
```

To not return the colleges the user already has, you can add a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM users_colleges AS uc2
    WHERE uc2.college_id = c.id
    AND uc2.user_id = '42'
)
```